# Using the wordpress loop within a plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm messing with a plugin that uses the wordpress loop.  I've been working on this for quite some time and can't seem to find a solution here.

Basically, I have the following functions within my plugins folder:

```
function fnp_getslideshow($settings) {
$query = new WP_Query( "posts_per_page=5");
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
# Code here
endwhile;
}
```

and

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'fnp_getslideshow', 10, 1 );
```

For some reason, I'm getting the following error: "Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\slb\wp-content\plugins\feature-post-slideshow\fnp_functions.php on line 80".  Any ideas as to what is causing this?

Comment: Wow, after typing this in, I realized the $query and $my_query difference, sorry for the waste of time.

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. Glad you were able to work it out. Also, thank you for using WP_Query. I feel blood vessels burst in my eyes every time I see query_posts.

Comment: @maiorano84 - I would upvote that comment a thousand times. If this question remains, I hope solely for that comment. Every time you use `query_posts()` God kills a kitten. Every time you use `new WP_Query()`.... something cute happens